# Sonar API Metrics

Tags: java, api, sonarqube, metrics, sonarqube-scan

Needed Sonar API to get the metrics from last analysed branch

I am fetching the sonar metrics using this api call. https://hostname.com/api/measures/component?component=projectkey&metricKeys=coverage,new_coverage

This gives me the coverage and new code coverage from the branch configured as main branch in the sonar. But I want the metrics from the branch which is last analysed branch. and I need this without specifying the branch names in the api call and I want it to fetch automatically from the latest analysed branch Can anyone help please.